# 3 divs next to each other of size 100% with another one as background that contains fluid photos

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-slides, fluid-images

I want to create a web page that has a photo as background, the background is 300% the screen wide and in every 33.33333% there is a photo centered that is responsive so it can maintain its ratio aspect.

My html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>aj</title>
    <link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <body/>
<div id="background"><img src="background.png"/> </div><!--These is the background                 image that should be displayed behind the other 3 images it is 1523x993 and i don't 
know how to make it stretch to be 3 time the size of the of the window -->
<div id="dvScreen1"><img src="2(1).png"/></div><!--These is one of the 3 photos that will be displayed above the background image, 
I want to make it centered in the window and responsive so if the window height changes than also its wide should change and the position 
should remain centered so that it won't display the next photo if the user makes the height of the window very small and the wide very large  -->
<div id="dvScreen2"><img src="l1.png"/></div><!-- these will be the second photo and should have the same properties as the first and should come to the right of the firs, between the first and the second -->
<div id="dvScreen3"><img src="l1.png"/></div> <!-- these photo will be the last so it will be floated left and will have the same responsive properties as the both will remain
centered and resize automatically on the x and y axes if the user resizes the window on y axes or the x axes--!>
    </body>

    </html>
```

My CSS code:

```
     body{
 height: 100%;
     overflow-x:vizible;
     width:300%;
     margin:0%;
     padding:0%;
 overflow-y:hidden;
 position;fixed;
     }
    #dvScreen1, #dvScreen2,#divScreen3{
    width:33.3333%;
    height:100%;
    clear:none;
    }
    #dvScreen1 {
    margin-left:0%;
    border:solid red 1px;
    margin-top:-100%;   
   }
#dvScreen2 {
    margin-left:33.33333%;
    border:solid black 1px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0%;
    }
    #dvScreen3{
    margin-left:66.66666%;
    border:solid blue 1px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0%;
    }
    #background{
    min-width:100%;
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
 }
```

Thank you for any help on the code

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: It does not work so I don't actually know where mistaking but the re-size doesn't work and also the divs are displayed on diagonal not inline and behind the 3 dis I want to add another one that will run as background

Comment: should I use <span>? but how?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a specific reason for having the background image set to 300% for size, it would be best to use the background-image property in your body portion of your CSS and use no-repeat as one of the values. When your browser renders the HTML document, the first visual object is the body and thus will stretch out the entire screen. Sometimes, however, the image may not cover the whole screen, which then I can see using the img tag where the background is set to 300%. Try the other approach first if you haven't already. As for the three other images, contain them in another div for the most optimal results. So rather than just have 3 secondary pictures, do something like:

```
<div id="pictures">

    <img src="2(1).png">

    <img src="l1.png">

    <img src="l1.png">

</div>
```

You would have to set a specific width on the container, but this allows you to code your css more cleanly like so:

```
#pictures{
    width:50%;
    margin: 0 25%; 
    /* This is an example size I came up with in my head */
}

#pictures img{
    /* This is to follow the basic format of the images */
    width:33.3333%;
    float:left;
    }
```

Of course, if each of the borders would need to be a different color, then just place the id's within each img tag, then only change the border properties. To maintain aspect, try making three different css files corresponding to a user's device: mobile, tablet, and pc and adjust values accordingly.